# How to use exponential function?

Tags: exponential-function

I know how to use exponential function when required in computer calculator but how does it work? I am still studying and our textbooks are not so detailed which gives us the idea how it works. I am using the function but still anyone can explain me in detail about how does it work?

Let $y = e^x $,
after taking value of $x = 1,2,3,4,5,6$.
Computer screen displays $e^1, e^2, e^3, e^4, e^5, e^6$. Then what?
I don't know how to do it now?
Please can anyone explain me? 
I am good learner can anyone help me?

Main purpose to learn exponential function is I got a question as follows 
set $A =\{(x,y):y=\exp(x) , x\ \text{belongs to}\ \mathbb{R}\ \text{set}\}$
how to write it in ROSTER form?

Roster form : In this method a set is described by listing elements, seperated by commas, within braces {}. The set of vowels of English Alphabet may be described as {a, e, i, o, u}.

Comment: What do you want to use the exponential function **for**?

Comment: @Mariano Suarez-Alvarez if A = {(x,y): y = e^x , x belongs to R } then write it in roster form.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have never heard of the term «roster form». In any case, please **edit** the question to include that information!

Comment: What do you mean by "how it works"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know which calculator or computer you use neither in which environment. It can be sufficiently clever to display $e^6$ because it noticed that the exponent is an integer. But, tell me what happens if you enter $e^{6.0}$ or $e^{6.00001}$.

For the practical calculation of an exponential, let me be very simple and consider that $$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$$ If you add $30$ terms (using $x=6$), you should arrive to a value of $403.4287934925$ while the exact value is $403.4287934927$

Comment: That is certainly *not* the exact value.

Comment: @JackM. For the number of significant figures I gave, I think it is ! By the way, the $exact$ value does not exist. Cheers.

Comment: Certainly the exact value exists, it is the irrational number $e^6$. Its decimal expansion *starts* with the value you gave, but it is not the complete (infinite) expansion, hence not exact.

Answer (score 1):

The exponential function can be represented by its Taylor series,  $$e^x=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^j}{j!} = 1+x+\frac {x^2}{2!}+ \cdots $$

Comment: ...which gives sharp approximation only if $x_0=0$, otherwise you need lots of terms, and this destroys the purpose of approximation